# Transferring values from a List to an objectarray in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, merge

I have a problem with transferring values from a list to an objectarray. The problem looks as following

```
ObjectArray = [
{Category:"Toys", CounterParty:"Lego", NrOfOccurences:"ToBeFixed", TotalAmount: 232,52},
{Category:"Games", CounterParty:"Minecraft", NrOfOccurences:"ToBeFixed", TotalAmount:190,68},
{Category:"Sports", CounterParty:"Soccer", NrOfOccurences:"ToBeFixed", TotalAmount: 28,95}]

List = [8,1,35]
```

The numbers in the list correspond with numbers in the objectArray (so 8 needs to be in the toys list, 1 in Games and 35 in Sports).

This is the eventual outcome i would like:

```
ObjectArray = [
{Category:"Toys", CounterParty:"Lego", NrOfOccurences:"8, TotalAmount: 232,52},
{Category:"Games", CounterParty:"Minecraft", NrOfOccurences:1, TotalAmount:190,68},
{Category:"Sports", CounterParty:"Soccer", NrOfOccurences:35, TotalAmount: 28,95}
```

Note: This is only a part of a much bigger list so hardcoding won't get the job done.

Hopefully this is enough info to inform anyone about the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: And the problem is? Use a loop and assign the value to the property -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Use `.map()` on `ObjectArray` and use the index to grab the number from the List array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple using for loop you can do it

```
 let ObjectArray = [
        { Category: "Toys", CounterParty: "Lego", NrOfOccurences: "ToBeFixed", TotalAmount: '232, 52' },
        { Category: "Games", CounterParty: "Minecraft", NrOfOccurences: "ToBeFixed", TotalAmount: '190, 68' },
        { Category: "Sports", CounterParty: "Soccer", NrOfOccurences: "ToBeFixed", TotalAmount: '28, 95' }
      ]

      let List = [8, 1, 35];

      for (let i = 0; i < List.length; i++) {
        ObjectArray[i].NrOfOccurences = List[i];
      }
      console.log(ObjectArray, 'ObjectArray');
```